# Is it possible to define a specific type for React Node children (and their props)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-functional-component

If I have a functional component...

```
const MyParent = (props:MyParentProps)=>{

 etc...
}
```

...is it possible in Typescript to define that all children must adhere to a specific type or interface?  eg

```
type IChild = (props:IChildProps)=> JSX.Element;
```

and...

Success

```
<MyParent>
  <Child/> // That implements IChild
  <Child/>// That implements IChild
</MyParent>
```

Failure

```
<MyParent>
  <BadChild/> // That doesn't implement IChild
  <Child/>// That implements IChild
</MyParent>
```

I just can't get Typescript to understand what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: [Yes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#children-type-checking). [`ReactElement` is a generic](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/8a2cc5d2a3736bd36e1d9f19365f6065606a2aa1/types/react/index.d.ts#L128-L135), so you can pass the `Child` and the `ChildProps` as type parameters. Then restrict `MyParentProps.children` to that

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

Instead, you can check the type of a `ReactElement` at runtime.

```
const MyChild = () => {
  return <></>;
};

type MyParentProps = {
  children: ReactElement | ReactElement[];
};

const MyParent = (props: MyParentProps) => {
  const children = (props.children instanceof Array) ? props.children : [props.children];
  for (const child of children)
    if (child.type !== MyChild)
      throw new Error("Children of MyParent must by MyChild.");
  
  return <></>;
}
```

But since it's in runtime, you can't check it against a type or interface.